# Hash function with ability to define its output generation length

Tags: matlab, hash, md5, hashcode, sha

I need to have a hash function in matlab which has capability to define its generated hashing length. For example, MD5 can generated hashing with length of 128 bits. However, I need to define various hashing function with designed lengths such as 10,16,20, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution if you employ the [CalcMD5](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25921-calcmd5) package from [FEX (Matlab File Exchange)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange):

```
function hash = myhash(len, value)
% len: The desired hash length. Integer
% value: The value to hash. String.

% Set this to whatever hash length your native hash algorithm employs.
nativehashlength = 32;
if len <= nativehashlength
    % Using the CalcMD5 package to obtain MD5 hash
    hash = CalcMD5(value);
    hash = hash(1:len);
else
    % Could to a lot of stuff, but i choose to hash the repeated value
    runs = ceil(len/nativehashlength);
    hash = [];
    aggregated = value;
    for r = 1:runs
        % Compute hash and add to hash string
        hash = [hash CalcMD5(aggregated)]; %#ok
        % Update the aggregate
        aggregated = [aggregated value]; %#ok
    end
    hash = hash(1:len);
end
end
```

This also works for strings/char arrays of short length, e.g.

```
>> myhash(100,'hello')
ans = 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c59223b431acfeb41e15d466d75de822307c99fb31087791f6317ad7c6da1433f1729436
>> myhash(2,'world') 
ans =
7d
```

Of course, the hash of size 10 for 'hello' will equal the first ten hash characters of the size 20 hash of 'hello', but it was not asked to generate very different hash functions depending on the desired hash size. this could, however, be easily implemented by salting the value with the requested hash size, for example.

There's more on FEX regarding hashing of stuff in Matlab, e.g. [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31272-datahash/content/DataHash.m).

Comment: Thank so much Dear @daniel wirtz. For comparison the result of hashing for verification, should I compare the hashing results with the same length at transmitter and receiver ?

Comment: i dont know what you're trying to use the hashing functions for. but if you want to verify a transmission there's no point in comparing different hash lengths. there's no additional security to that. also, any way (including mine) you use to "transform" the native hash function without any additional value-dependent information does not make it safer to use/harder to crack than the "plain" native hash function; just be warned.

Comment: Dear Daniel Wirrtz I want to perform hash on data (D)  to change it to (H1) at sender then hiding inside the image and transmit it through a channel. At receiver, I need to extract the data (H2) which is hided in image. Now my question is How do I compare extracted data (H2) which is hashed and original data (D)? I need to compute Bit error. Thanks.

Comment: how do you compare? well you transmit the generated hash code and re-compute the hash on the other side and compare the two hash values. in matlab this can be done using e.g. "strcmp". otherwise you need to refine your question and consider opening a new one if the scope changes too much.

Comment: tnx so much dear Ddaniel